# On Start-up, Ubuntu Turns Off Laptop Monitor - Please Help

Tags: boot, display

I'm experiencing a baffling problem, as described in the title. Here is more detail:

When I start up my laptop, the monitor turns on, like normal, and displays the HP logo. Usually, after displaying the HP logo the HP logo will be displayed with the Ubuntu logo. However, for the past three days, instead of displaying the Ubuntu logo the laptop screen simply turns off. Note that this is not a blank screen or a blue screen of death; the screen is definitely just turned off.

Fortunately, I am still able to use the computer by connecting a second monitor via HDMI. It is worth noting, however, that when the external monitor is connected Ubuntu is still recognizing the presence of the laptop monitor and still considers that to be the primary display. Consequently, I changed the primary display to the external monitor.

Part of me thinks that this is a hardware problem because it didn't start until this past Thursday, which was a day in which I moved to a new apartment. It is certainly believable that the laptop received an unfortunate knock during the move. But, if it is a hardware problem, why would the display only turn off once Ubuntu started up?

My system details are below. Any thoughts or suggestions you could provide are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Memory: 15.5 GB

Processor: Intel Core i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz x 8

Graphics: NV118 / Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)

Disk Capacity: 256.1 GB

OS Name: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

OS Type: 64-bit

GNOME Version: 3.36.8

Windowing System: X11

Computer Model: HP Probook 450 G6

ProdID 5YH15UT#ABA

Comment: The backlight on some laptops can be set to 0 (off).  Your computer may be saving and restoring the backlight state.  I recall reading about someone having a similar problem as yours with a dual video card system.  In that case, video started working again after plugging in an external monitor in mirror mode.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! That sounds like a reasonable conclusion. But how do I access the backlight settings? I currently have an external monitor set up in mirror mode and the laptop monitor is still off. Thank you.

Comment: Usually there are keys to control the backlight when pressed along with the Fn key.  The icon looks like the sun.  You can also try command line tools, like `xbacklight` or `light`.  If those don't work, you can look at the output of `dmesg` to see if there are any errors or messages to indicate something else that might be going on, like missing firmware files.